# Myeclipse not opening in Windows 8

Tags: tomcat, windows-8, myeclipse

Will Myeclipse 10 work in Windows 8. I am facing few problem, it does not opening most of the time when I click on the icon and when it opens and when I try to run tomacat, it disappears completely.

Any help!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

MyEclipse has been tested with Windows 8 and should work just fine.

Exactly what version of MyEclipse are you using, what happens when you double click the icon?

Comment: Hi, i downloaded a latest trail version of Bling (I think it is V10). When i click on the ICON nothing happens, I checked task manager and i dont see any process running there too.

Comment: I restarted my machine quite a number of time and then it worked. However when i tried to run the server(Tomcat) from MyEclipse, it suddenly disappears...and it doen't show up in the task manager either.